# Load package from Debian Proxy on Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: docker, debian, nexus, apt

I want to load debian packages (curl, gnupg2, etc.) from an debian proxy of a nexus repository manager server on building of an docker image.

But package could not be located.

How do I have to setup my setting (sources.list etc) and how do I have to search for the packages?

I am using Nexus Pro 3.43

When I browse through repository on nexus browser, locate the package and download it, the dowload link is

`https://exampleurl.org/repository/debian-bullseye/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.74.0-1.3+b1_amd64.deb`

I tried to modify etc/appt/sources.list by Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM example_dtr/python:3.9.15-slim-buster AS dev

RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://exampleurl.org/repository/debian-bullseye/dists buster InRelease" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN echo "exampleurl.org" >> /etc/apt/auth.conf
RUN echo "login USER" >> /etc/apt/auth.conf
RUN echo "password PWD" >> /etc/apt/auth.conf
```

But this settings may be wrong. When I run

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl
```

or

```
RUN apt install pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_all
```

I allwas get following exceptions like this one:

```
 > [ 7/12] RUN apt install pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_all:
#12 0.384
#12 0.384 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#12 0.384
#12 0.387 Reading package lists...
#12 0.393 Building dependency tree...
#12 0.393 Reading state information...
#12 0.394 E: Unable to locate package pool/main/g/gnupg2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `RUN apt-get update` to the Dockerfile in order to include the new packages of the repo when you appended the sources.list, here:

```
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://exampleurl.org/repository/debian-bullseye/dists buster InRelease" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you've only just added a software repository (PPA or Debian repository), you'll have to run `apt-get update`, otherwise the source won't be recognized, since not indexed yet.

```
FROM example_dtr/python:3.9.15-slim-buster AS dev
    
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://exampleurl.org/repository/debian-bullseye/dists buster InRelease" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "exampleurl.org" >> /etc/apt/auth.conf
RUN echo "login USER" >> /etc/apt/auth.conf
RUN echo "password PWD" >> /etc/apt/auth.conf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
```